# Проблема со студией

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

## Visual Stidio 2013 Ultimate

- При нажатии кнопки "Создать проект" начинают грузиться шаблоны и
  студия зависает.
- Долго виснет и ничего в итоге не происходит.
- Раньше    такой проблемы не было.
- Уже готовые проекты открываются, но новые    создать не могу.

  У меня Windows 10 (64bit)
  [image: Скриншот самой ошибки]

Comment: Проект какой? Не Xamarin случаем? Если он, то там была подобная проблема у меня, если криво установлен SDK/NDK/JAVA.

Comment: Просто нажимаю кнопку создать проект, должно появится окно выбора проекта, но студия зависает

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `devenv.exe /installvstemplates`, либо [сбросить](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx) настройки студии.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не помогло

Comment: На личном опыте проверено, что , к примеру, 2015 студия на Win10 x64 работает без проблем. Возможно, вам стоит либо переустановить текущую версию студии, либо скачать более новую версию.

Comment: версия студии значения не имеет, все версии, кроме, может быть, самых ранних, работают нормально. Восстановите настройки студии встроенными средствами или переустановите, если восстановление не помогает. SSD не панацея, они сыплются также как механика, в среднем, даже быстрее, если используете GIT и/или играете.